# How well known were the events of the original “Star Wars” trilogy in the general galaxy? Or was it all about clandestine special operations missions?

Tags: star-wars

**Preface:** I am aware that there are other threads that discuss the Jedi/Sith aspects of common knowledge in the *Star Wars* universe such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105582/why-are-there-people-who-dont-believe-jedi-ever-exist), [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/why-would-the-force-become-so-mysterious-and-unrecognized-after-only-20-years) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86839/why-did-nobody-know-about-the-sith-empire). My question is not about knowledge of the Jedi/Sith stuff as much as the “wars” of *Star Wars* itself. To me it seems as if the general population of the galaxy knows they are oppressed, but are not really aware there is an active war to end that oppression regardless of the “religious” aspect that seems to have started it all.

---

So the some of the trailers for the new film, *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* have a key scene where Han Solo states:

> It’s true. All of it. The Dark Side. The Jedi. They’re real.

Okay, so I understand how the whole mystical concept of “The Force” might have been lost by the sands of time. But what about the rest of it? Objectively thinking of how the original trilogy was presented it seems everything was secretive or clandestine in many ways:

- ***Star Wars***: The mission to recover the Death Star plans from the Rebels was carried out by one Star Destroyer lead by Darth Vader. When the idea the plans were jettisoned to Tatooine in an escape pod, Stormtroopers are sent to the planet, but everything is somewhat secretive. Even the massacre of the Jawas was done in a way to make it seem as if Tusken Raiders (aka: Sand People) carried out the attack. The rest of the film follows the same notes including the attack on Yavin moon that contained the secret rebel base.
- ***The Empire Strikes Back***: Again, Darth Vader is hunting down Rebels and they are hiding on an ice planet seemingly as far away from everything as possible. The trip to see Yoda on Dagobah was not shared by Luke with anyone, and when Han Solo heads to Bespin, it’s to seek refuge. And heck, even Lando Calrissian brags about how his operation in Cloud City is small enough to not attract the attention of the Empire. So everything that happens there is known only to the parties involved it seems.
- ***Return of the Jedi***: The rescue of Han Solo from Tatooine is yet another clandestine operation carried out by a small group of friends trying to save the life of a fellow friend. When Jabba dies and his ships are destroyed, who cares and who knows what happened outside of that group? Jabba’s just a huge crime lord and his death would not mean much to other criminals let alone raise an eyebrow by others. Then the whole Death Star II operation on Endor is yet again, a secret operation.

And there we go. It seems that everything that transpires in the the original trilogy are all special operations and “need to know” operations at best carried out by two opposing sides who might be fighting for larger power, but it’s not like — for example — a World War II struggle it seems. It all seems like small scale operations in a lager conflict much like action films such as ***[The Guns of Navarone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guns_of_Navarone_(film))*** or ***[Where Eagles Dare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Eagles_Dare)***.

So in this context, what exactly did the “wars” in the *Star Wars* actually mean as far as awareness goes throughout the galaxy? My desire for “canon” extends into  the modern definition of *Star Wars* canon which means Disney canon as well; no fan-fiction or wild guesses please.

Again, it seems the new series of films will you touch on how “legendary” yet not real these events seem to contemporary residents in the *Star Wars* universe goes. But is there an canonical material that explicitly states something like, “The war against the Empire was important, yet not directly known by most inhabitants in the galaxy/universe of *Star Wars*.”

PS: FWIW, this all seems odd to me because to my knowledge — in the context of our own conflicts on Earth — even in pre-Internet/pre-modern communication times, wars and conflicts were known or conveyed in some way to even the most menial people in society. You talk to someone about the Crusades, the Civil War or even World War I nowadays people at least know that some kind of war happened even if they do not know any specifics of the conflict. But in the *Star Wars* universe, average citizens seem fairly clueless despite having apparently better technology and communication methods.

Comment: Could be a dupe of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105582/why-are-there-people-who-dont-believe-jedi-ever-exist) (closed as a dupe of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/why-would-the-force-become-so-mysterious-and-unrecognized-after-only-20-years)) or [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86839/why-did-nobody-know-about-the-sith-empire)?

Comment: Do you want Disney canon, or real canon, answer?

Comment: How many modern day schoolkids recognize military significance of the Verdun? Kursk? How many were aware of Navajo battle language before the film came out? How many were even aware that Greece was involved in WWII (in America) before Guns of Navarone

Comment: Your main question seems to be ***So in this context, what exactly did the “wars” in the Star Wars actually mean as far as awareness goes throughout the galaxy?***  This is related to my question, [Which wars are Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102167/which-wars-are-star-wars)

Comment: @JakeGould : Thanks.  That's why I say related (rather than dupe).  :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay I'll toss in a Legends answer.

Looking at the Empire's citizens' view of the Republic in the *X-Wing* series we see much propaganda and just lies spread to discourage rebel support. Coruscant (and probably other planets) had large museums constructed as monuments to the emperor and the empire.

> All the displays... were slanted toward making the viewers believe
>   everything the Emperor had done had been for their specific good.

and a long quote, well worth the read:

> A holographic image of Darth Vader sizzled to life when wedge had
>   approached. "Behold my Master and weep. He has been stolen from us by
>   those who embrace hatred. The Emperor had learned the rebels had
>   stolen plans for a Planetary ore extractor and intended to use the one
>   they fabricated on Endor on inhabited planets. He assembled his fleet,
>   and heedless of personal danger, he had me take him to Endor. He
>   infiltrated the half-completed extractor, offering these Rebels his
>   forgiveness and a hand of friendship. They rejected him and attacked
>   his fleet. My master had no alternative but to destroy this Death Star
>   himself, perishing in the process so his citizens could live on. I was
>   slain with him, but my death did not distress me, for it came in
>   service to my master.

So much of what the citizens of the Empire hear is completely fabricated or twisted against the Rebels.

As for Alderaan's destruction, while it is not really known what happened specifically to the planet, the Rebels are blamed for it:

> The fear that lingered in everyone's heart concerning the destruction
>   of Alderaan was shifted into fear directed at the Rebellion.

Edit: I found another mention of propaganda,

> "If not for various holodramas that painted Jedi Knights as villains..."
>   <sub>*X-Wing: The Bacta War* Chapter 1 page 3</sub>

So even the media is involved in the distortion of the truth. Such sources of information may be the only info some individuals see and so have no reason to question their validity.

Answer (score 10):

**A New Hope**

The specifics of Rogue Squadron and the subsequent efforts to transport the Death Star plans were not public knowledge.

The destruction of Alderaan was well-publicized, and intentionally so.

> Dantooine is too remote to make an effective demonstration - Tarkin

Its destruction, combined with the Empire's unsubtle attempt to kill off any off-world Alderannians, lead to a surge in anti-Imperial sentiment. This in-universe example of Rebel propaganda demonstrates this.

[image]

Confusion followed the first Death Star's destruction. According to *Lost Stars*, it was initially assumed to be Rebel lies by some. However, it was soon well-known enough for the Rebel forced to be "bolstered," according to *Battlefront: Twilight Company*. The Hutt Council also publicly acknowledged it, according to *The Rebel Files*. It was not initially publicized that Luke did it. However, by the time of *Bloodline*, six years before *The Force Awakens*, it was public knowledge. However, a faction of "[Death Star truthers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Centrists)" who believed the Death Star was sabotaged by a rogue Imperial had also arisen at this point.

> The Bureau distributed more than twenty thousand recordings showing Yavin 4 telemetry of the destruction of the Death Star. - *Propaganda*

> For his safety, Rebel messagesmiths avoided publicizing Luke Skywalker’s name, but the tale of a young Rebel pilot with minimal combat experience who destroyed the Empire’s ultimate weapon was too powerful to keep secret for long. - *Propaganda*

**The Empire Strikes Back**

The results of the Battle of Hoth were well-known, as shown by the following conversation between two smugglers in *Uprising*.

> "You have heard of Hoth, I assume?"
>
> "Snowball the Rebels were hiding on, right?"
>
> "Before the Imperials struck a year ago, yes. Now the battleground is littered with wreckage."

Additionally, the battle was well-documented and discussed by in-universe historians, according to *Complete Locations*.

*From a Certain Point of View: The Empire Strikes Back* has many examples of Cloud City citizens evacuating from the platform due to the Empire's incursion. Knowledge of their presence there would therefore be in the public, though likely not of much interest to most.

Luke and Leia's parentage is not publicly exposed until *Bloodline.*

**Return of the Jedi**

Jabba the Hutt was an extremely important figure in the underworld. He headed the Hutt Council which held enough power to negotiate with the Empire itself. His death, as well as the power vacuum it created, were public knowledge.

> "I know that things are changing. Not just in the galaxy, but here at home, too. The Hutts still haven't shaken out who's next up to fill Jabba's throne... Seems like this might be a new day for Tatooine." - Vanth, *Aftermath*

The results of the Battle of Endor were also broadcast across the galaxy, as seen in media such as *The Mandalorian* and *Uprising*.

[image]

[image]

Efforts such as the Iron Blockade, also seen in *Uprising*, attempted to censor the results of the battle, but quickly fell through. The Emperor and Vader's deaths, and the Empire's loss, were soon well-known. However, much of the public believed that Palpatine was assassinated by the Rebellion (*Alphabet Squadron*).

Comment: A galaxy is a huge place, unimaginably huge to most people. Even if FTL travel and communication are common place it feels unlikely that general knowledge of specific events would travel outside of a couple hundred lightyears, or perhaps a few thousand for a really big event. Aside from the destruction of the Death Stars, which likely would have had massive galactic-scale Imperial propaganda campaigns surrounding them beforehand, it's hard to believe that the general populace would be aware of what happened on an insignificant ice ball or a wildcat mining operation half a galaxy away.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the galaxy knew about the destruction of Alderaan and were very upset about it.  The people knew about the battles of Yavin and Endor, who won those battles and who lost them.

The galaxy learned these things by the Holonet transmissions sent across the galaxy. There were mass defections after the battles of Yavin and Endor, top imperial leadership  was lost at both Yavin and Endor and the deaths of Vader, and the Emperor. The people  learned this by the way of the Holonet transmissions broadcast around the entire galaxy. The information was passed on by both imperial and rebel soldiers.

This information was told in the *Aftermath* trilogy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  These are canon books, which makes this a fairly strong answer.  You could still improve it by adding specific quotes from the book(s) to demonstrate the general population's view.

Answer (score 4):

*Given that the current answers to this question are now several years old, and canon marches on, I'd like to add that two instances in *The Mandalorian* shed new light on this question.*

---

In season 1’s [Chapter 4: Sanctuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_4:_Sanctuary), Cara Dune is discussing with Din Djarin about her time as a Rebel drop trooper. While as a member of the Rebel/New Republic armed forces, she would have inside knowledge, she discusses the Battle of Endor as if Djarin would be well aware of what happened there.

> “Saw most of my action mopping up after Endor. Mostly Ex-Imperial Warlords. They wanted it fast and quiet. They'd send us in on the drop ships. No support, just us. Then when the Imps were gone, the politics started.”

Then in season 2’s [Chapter 9: The Marshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_9:_The_Marshal), the titular character, Cobb Vanth marshal of a backwater town in the middle of nowhere on Tatooine recounts a flashback.

> “It started after we got news of the Death Star blowing up. The second one, that is.”

We have a clear shot during this flashback of the Holonet news broadcasting the actual destruction of the second Death Star. Showing that even in the far flung parts of the galaxy, this news was quickly disseminated to all and sundry.

[image: Still from The Mandalorian S2E01 showing holonet footage of the destruction of the second Death Star]

So, while there may be some aspects of the original trilogy which are on a need-to-know basis, the destruction of the second Death Star by Rebel Alliance is widely known throughout the galaxy.

Answer (score 2):

I pretty sure the instant destruction/vaporization of an entire Core planet (Alderaan) and their population would be quite notorious and couldn't brushed under rug as a casualty of a "special op". If we're using Earth wars as an analogy, it's gonna be a long time before the nuking of Hiroshima & Nagasaki falls into legend/did-it-really-happen category and shows up on Snopes.

Comment: Disagree, people already don't believe the Holocaust happened